# Mq Connection error 2058

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq, mq

I have a spring core application with config below.

I'm using UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter, MQQueueConnectionFactory and jms-listener.

```
    <jms:listener-container container-type="default"
    connection-factory="userConnectionFactory" acknowledge="auto">
        <jms:listener destination="${QUEUE_NAME_IN_GEN}" ref="messageListener"
        method="onMessage" />
    </jms:listener-container>

    <bean id="userConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <ref bean="mqConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="${MQ_USER_ID}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName">
        <value>${MQ_HOST_NAME}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="port">
        <value>${MQ_PORT}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="queueManager">
        <value>${QUEUE_MANAGER}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="transportType">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

on application startup, listener stars perfectly one one machine.
when I try with same artifacts on a different server, listener fails to start with following error:

```
[org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1] ERROR org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:909) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'R.ABCDEF' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'myhost:dev'; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2058
MQJE036: Queue manager rejected connection attempt
```

To figure out if it's something to do with Unix account privilege issue on the second server, I wrote a simple MQ Client application. This program can connect to this queue manager and read messages from it.

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

A 2058 suggests that the queue manager name is incorrect. According to the technote from IBM that's the most common cause, however there are others.

The following extract is taken from this [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21166938):

> Ensure that the queue manager name is specified correctly on:
>
> - MQCONN API calls
> - QREMOTE object definitions
> - Client connection channel definitions
>
> Debugging QCF, TCF, or Client connection problems are much more complex.
>
> - Ensure that the connection request is routed to the intended machine and queue manager.
> - Verify that the listener program is starting the channel on the correct queue manager.
> - Ensure that the specifications for the client environment variables are correct.
> - mqserver
> - mqchllib
> - mqchltab
>
> If you are using a client channel table (amqclchl.tab), then verify that your client connection channel definition has the correct queue manager name (QMNAME) specified.
>
> - Specify the correct queue manager name.
> - Correct channel routing problems.
> - Correct inetd listener configuration problems.
> - Correct client related configuration problems.